Is a fission-fusion battery physically possible?
I'm not a physicist, so forgive me if this question is obvious, or if I'm detracting from the forum's goals (not sure if this is analogous to math exchange or math overflow).
My understanding of nuclear energy is that one can get more energy from the breaking of an atom than the energy spent to break it. Naturally fissile materials (like certain isotopes of uranium) have the extra benefit of being breakable by the energy released by their own fission, leading to a chain reaction.
Likewise, fusion reactions require more energy than they take (at the current technological level).
So, it seems that both can be coupled to produce a very energetically dense battery: Take a non-fissile material and initiate fission reactions. Since they are not a chain reaction the process will continue as long as an initial energy is provided (perhaps from a conventional battery) with a possible net positive. However, the process will cease immediately once energy is no longer provided, or the material in the battery is spent, turned into smaller atoms.
Once that happens, fusion can be used to reconstitute the battery to its original state at the cost of energy.
I'm sure there's something impeding the use of this technique, otherwise people would have deployed it. What stops this use?

To make an energy storage device, you want a physical process that wants to happen on its own spontaneously.  To store energy in it, you input energy to force the reverse process, and then the spontaneous process will release the energy again.  The simplest example may be pumping water into a reservoir, and then allowing it to flow out under gravity, driving a turbine.
What you've proposed seems to be putting energy in to fission atoms, and then putting energy in again to fuse them.
We currently use fissile material like plutonium as batteries (eg RTGs in the Voyager craft) because it wants to spontaneously fission.  We "create" or "charge" these batteries if you like by putting Uranium in a nuclear reactor and transforming it into Plutonium that will easily fission. However if you wanted to truly store the energy from scratch to make a rechargeable battery, you would need a supernova-like environment that fused the Uranium in the first place. As you mentioned, not technologically feasible.

I see your point. I guess it depends on the definition of battery. I'm aware of "atomic batteries" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_battery), but for me they are better defined as generators and not as batteries (as they consume a "fuel"). I guess my fissile battery would also fall in this category since it would require energy to be started.

https://xkcd.com/2115/


Once that happens, fusion can be used to reconstitute the battery to its original state at the cost of energy.

Leaving aside the (very many) practical issues with this approach, the second law of thermodynamics tells us that any method of restoring the battery to its initial state will require the input of at least as much energy as you extracted from the battery in the first place (and probably a whole lot more). If this were not so, then you would have invented a perpetual motion machine.

True, but that's how batteries work no? The same is true for the battery bank in my phone. Some energy is loss in the form of heat.

@JMenezes Ok, then I am missing the point of your question. You appear to be proposing a highly complex and dangerous nuclear process that offers no advantages over the simple chemical processes that drive an ordinary rechargeable battery.

@gandalf61 practical concerns aside, the energy density of such a battery would likely be far greater than a chemical battery, which could technically be counted as an advantage.

@gandalf61, paulina is right. Fundamentally the question is purely theoretical. Can we "solve" modern battery struggles with energy density by storing the energy in the nuclei of the atom instead of their electrons? Of course, there is a near-infinite number of reasons of why such devices is impractical/impossible/expensive, at the enginnering level, but is it theoretically possible?
